# How can I copy my ubuntu from HDD to external usb Hard drive

Tags: dual-boot, hard-drive, live-usb, external-hdd

I have Ubuntu installed on my HP G7000 laptop and I would like to copy files from my internal hard drive to USB hard drive, so I could Install Windows to my computer, but still be able to use Ubuntu. I don`t have enough space left on my internal hard drive so dual boot wont work.

Comment: ...and what files do you want to copy? What does "my ubuntu" means to you exactly?

Comment: It is unlikely (from your question) that you have the skills to attempt to **modify** an already installed Ubuntu Linux instance, to reconfigure it's installed location. *While this is possible, you will most likely break your existing applications.* You may need to do a fresh install of Ubuntu, to the external (or removable) media, and then to transfer any settings (or data). You could then **just** install Windows (with the external Linux not attached/present), overwriting any existing configuration.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `dd` command

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sdx of=/dev/usbx bs=1m
```

For more information you can read the following forum: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1561005